# Meaning of the "forthcoming" in this sentence

Tags: meaning, adjectives

> I'm going to be as forthcoming as I can be, Mr. Anderson.

from The Matrix.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It means "willing to share information" about something.

From NOAD:

> **forthcoming** 2 • (of a person) willing to divulge information : *their daughter had never been forthcoming about her time in Europe*.

Answer (score 0):

Definitions of [Forthcoming](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/forthcoming)

I would think that the meaning here is either

> "frank and cooperative; candid "In his
>   testimony, the senator could have been
>   more forthcoming."

Or

> "friendly and outgoing; sociable."

Depending on the context.